# Form isn't available in template with django_filters

Tags: python, django, forms, debugging, django-filter

I'm trying to build data filtering paginated page. Here is my filter

```
from shop.models import CC
import django_filters

name_values = [("", "---------")] + list(CC.objects.values_list('name', 'name').distinct())
city_values = [("", "---------")] + list(CC.objects.values_list('city', 'city').distinct())


class CCFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    name = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(choices=name_values)
    city = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(choices=city_values)

    class Meta:
        model = CC
        fields = {
            'name': ['exact'],
            'city': ['exact'],
        }
```

View:

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class BuyView(ListView):
    paginate_by = '25'
    queryset = CC.objects.all()
    context_object_name = "ccs"
    template_name = "buy.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(BuyView, self).get_queryset()
        queryset = CCFilter(self.request.GET, queryset)
        return queryset

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BuyView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['cart'] = Cart.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        return context

    def get_paginate_by(self, queryset):
        """
        Paginate by specified value in querystring, or use default class property value.
        """
        return self.request.GET.get('per_page', self.paginate_by)
```

Model:

```
class CC(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(max_length=19, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
```

In [documentation](http://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#the-view) it's written that form object is available as context property in template. But when I do `{{ ccs.form|crispy }}` nothing appears. Though I'm able to filter data with get requests like `?name=christian`, it works well. But how can I access form?

Comment: You are trying to access `css.form`, but your `css` object is just a list (`QuerySet` to be precise) of filtered objects. Take a look on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#making-friendly-template-contexts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation shows that you can either write a view and pass the filter to the template manually, or use the built in `FilterView`. You are currently using Django's `ListView`, so the filter won't be passed to the template unless you do it explicitly.

You could try changing your view to use `FilterView` instead. It would look something like this. I've left out the pagination code to keep it simple.

```
from django_filters.views import FilterView

@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class BuyView(FilterView):
    filterset_class = CCFilter
    template_name = "buy.html"
    context_object_name = "ccs"

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(BuyView, self).get_queryset()
        queryset = CCFilter(self.request.GET, queryset)
        return queryset

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BuyView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['cart'] = Cart.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        return context
```

In the template, you can access the filter with `{{ filter }}`, and the form with `{{ filter.form }}`

Comment: Can you please give a hint, which way can I implement pagination with FilterView?

Comment: The filter view uses `MultipleObjectMixin`, so the pagination code in your question might work. I'm not 100% sure, so I left it out. I would use an integer i.e. `paginate_by = 25` instead of a string.

Comment: Thanks for clear explanation. I managed to get it work with pure pagination extension.